# Using array efficiently to disable buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex3

For example i have values inside array.

Those values are the IDs of buttons. My question is how to use array efficiently to disable the buttons?

Comment: Be more specific, show some code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: var buttons = new Array("button1","button2","button3"); I have no idea where to start.. What I did is when buttons are pressed, their IDs will be stored in an array. I also created a button that will disable those buttons inside the array... that's where I want to put the code.

Comment: Just loop through the array and set the button states to disabled then. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an array like in comments:

```
var buttons:Array=new Array('button1','button2','button3');
```

And you have button objects with names in your MC, namely button1, button2, button3. Use the following:

```
for each (var s:String in buttons) this[s].disable();
```

where "disable" is whatever you need to do to disable the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the buttons themselves in an array (or a Vector), it will be easier than using ids:

```
private var _clickedButtons:Array = [];

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  _clickedButtons.push(e.currentTarget);
}
```

and then browse this array to disabled them

```
function disableButtons():void
{
  for each(var button:Button in _clickedButtons)
  {
    button.enabled = false;
  }
}
```